# Error deleting metadata objects from packaging org during 1GP package creation

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to create a 1GP package using [cumulusci][1] as part of workflow there is a step "deploy_packaging.uninstall_packaged_incremental" where it deletes metadata from the packaging org if it does not exist in the code. In the packaging org, the org has permission to delete metadata.
In the past I have released 1GP packages from the same packaging org, but now I am facing a problem with deleting metadata.

The error I am having is the following. How can I get past this error ? Any ideas ?

I am thinking permission to delete packaged components from the packaging org. I can see the stale custom metadata in the org that exists, when I am trying to delete it is prompting to type "Yes" when I am clicking delete, it is telling me I cannot delete managed package components.

```
[05/26/22 10:15:01] Deleting metadata:                                                                                                                                         
                        CustomField: One_Degree_Attribute_Setting__mdt.Active__c                                                                                               
                        CustomField: One_Degree_Attribute_Setting__mdt.Attribute_Tag__c                                                                                        
                        CustomField: One_Degree_Attribute_Setting__mdt.Last_Run_Datetime__c                                                                                    
                        CustomField: One_Degree_Zipcode_Search__mdt.Zipcode__c                                                                                                 
                        CustomField: One_Degree_Zipcode_Search__mdt.lat__c                                                                                                     
                        CustomField: One_Degree_Zipcode_Search__mdt.long__c                                                                                                    
                        CustomMetadata: One_Degree_Attribute_Setting.health_clinic                                                                                             
                        CustomMetadata: One_Degree_Zipcode_Search.X94118                                                                                                       
                        CustomObject: One_Degree_Attribute_Setting__mdt                                                                                                        
                        CustomObject: One_Degree_Zipcode_Search__mdt                                                                                                           
                        Layout: One_Degree_Attribute_Setting__mdt-One Degree Attribute Setting Layout                                                                          
                        Layout: One_Degree_Zipcode_Search__mdt-One Degree Zipcode Search Layout                                                                                
                    Deleting metadata in package OneDegree from target org                                                                                                     
                    Pending                                                                                                                                                    
[05/26/22 10:15:02] [Pending]: next check in 1 seconds                                                                                                                         
[05/26/22 10:15:03] [Pending]: next check in 1 seconds                                                                                                                         
[05/26/22 10:15:04] [Pending]: next check in 2 seconds                                                                                                                         
[05/26/22 10:15:06] [Done]                                                                                                                                                     
[05/26/22 10:15:08] [Failed]: Update of CustomMetadata One_Degree_Attribute_Setting.health_clinic: Error: Cannot delete managed object                                         
                                                                                                                                                                               
                    Update of CustomField One_Degree_Attribute_Setting__mdt.Last_Run_Datetime__c: Error: Cannot delete managed object                                          
                                                                                                                                                                               
                    Update of CustomField One_Degree_Attribute_Setting__mdt.Active__c: Error: Cannot delete managed object                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                               
                    Update of CustomField One_Degree_Zipcode_Search__mdt.long__c: Error: Cannot delete managed object  


  [1]: https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/managed_package.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The Metadata API simply mirrors the manageability rules you're encountering in the org's package UI when trying to delete those fields.  So, in this case CumulusCI is triggering the error which is working as expected.

The uninstall_packaged_incremental task is intended to ensure you don't wind up with stale metadata (i.e. metadata in the packaging org that's not in git) in the package version you're creating.  If for some reason it finds stale metadata and can't delete it, it should fail so you don't wind up with a "corrupted" package version.

Unfortunately, in this particular case you're trying to delete fields on a CustomMetadataType rather than a CustomObject which appears to be prohibited by the guard rails (manageability rules) of managed packaging.

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_custom_metadata_types
- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_req_managed_pkgs.htm&type=5

Normally, you would need to get the Delete Components from Managed Packages permission applied to your packaging org per https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000326278&type=1